# Rails: Couldn't find Image without an ID error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a two models, Items and Images. Under image model belongs_to :item and the item model has:many :images.

The image model has an item_id attribute.

Under the Items viewer I'm trying to display the images associated with each item. So for example I'd like to display image with item_id 1000 mapping onto Item with ID 1000.

I get a Couldn't find Image with an ID error.

The Viewer looks like this:

```
<h1>Listing items - temporary testing page</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Item title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Image link</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= item.brand %></td>
    <td><%= item.item_title %></td>
    <td><%= item.description %></td>
    <td><%= item.image_id %></td>
    <td><%= image_tag @findimages.small_img %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', item %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }     %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Item', new_item_path %>
```

The Items Controller like this:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /items
  # GET /items.json
  def index
    @items = Item.all(params[:id])
    @findimages = Image.find(params[:item_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @items }
    end
  end
.
.
.
```

Help for a noob would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like there is no image with params[:item_id]

1. use @findimages = Image.find(params[:item_id]) if params[:item_id]
2. use validates_presence_of :item_id in image.rb
3. Item.all(params[:id]) - wrong
   Item.find(params[:id]) of Item.all
4. You are using :item_id - thats right. Next you shoud use has_one :image in item.rb and belongs_to :item in image.rb. so your code will looks like:

   ```
   def index  
     @items = Item.all
   ```

and in view

```
<td><%= image_tag item.image.small_img %></td>
```

UPD: enter rails console and ensure that all images has an item_id by:

```
Image.where(:item_id => nil)
```

UPD2: Do not use pgadmin with rails, rails - best database administration tool.

Comment: Ok, this works - for my education, would you mind explaining why params[:item_id] did not bring up the image but it did when you wrote @findimages = Image.find(params[:item_id]) if params[:item_id]? Also why is pgadmin not a good admin tool?

Comment: It is inapropriate to change any data instead of using rails methods, there are many relations between data, u can delete item, but images still exist. or u can delete item but image will still try to find it by item_id and it chrashes your application. its is simple example

Comment: about @findimages:
perhaps you miss something if params[:item_id] exist it calls Image.find... it allow us to avoid exeption. in your case seems like there is  wrong item_id

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@findimages = Image.find(params[:item_id])
```

To

```
@findimages = Image.find_by_id(params[:item_id])
```

Ref [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001788) it states that `If no record can be found for all of the listed ids, then RecordNotFound will be raised.`

Where as `find_by_id` it will return `nil` when no record found for given id

Comment: Thanks for that, the funny thing is there is a record in the database and it's not picking it up. However the record was inputed on the backend using pgadmin 3 (using Postgres) and all relevant records are there - would this have an impact?